# I have a model stuck on "Deploying". How do I resolve?

Tags: microsoft-translator

In the Custom Translator portal, I have two models stuck in Deploying state. There is no option to cancel, and I can't delete a deploying model.

I tried adding a second model thinking I could deploy that one, but I do not have the option to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Please contact custommt@microsoft.com with the details of your workspace and model